# Creating a Calendar using javafx

Tags: java, javafx, calendar

I am a little stumped on how to get started on this project I have in front of me. I simply need to create a calendar on a javafx stage for the current date with two simple next / prior buttons to go between months.

So far I have just created the minimum, a blank stage to appear.

```
public class Calendar extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Java Calendar");
    Pane base = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(base, 500, 300);


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

}

I had noticed under java documentation that there is a calendar class under java.util, however the documentation was rather confusing to me on how to implement it. Basically I want to ask, what is the best way to approach this? Would you be able to show me through the basics of how this or another Calendar class works? Or would I be best off using a grid pane, and switch between what scene is shown on the stage when I click the next or prior button?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: i don´t know if you are allowed to (sounds like an assignment), but [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm) could be worth a read.

Comment: Your question is really too broad: you need to try something and see if you can get it to work. This forum is for specific programming questions (so you can post back here if you get stuck, but you really need to start writing the application first). Your question doesn't really make sense as you are asking to choose between two unrelated aspects of the application. `java.util.Calendar` simply represents data (don't use it, use the new [`java.time` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) instead. `GridPane`, `Stage`, `Scene` are parts of the UI. Use those.

Comment: James_D, I am asking this now, because I realize I can just start using a gridPane, but that could take a bit of time, when there could be a class I could have used and done it in next to no time at all. I am just unfamiliar with whatever class I could possible use, which is why I am asking if it is possible to use a class or not.

@KevinEsche, I will take a look at it real quick, thank you! Even though it is an assignment we are allowed a lot of freedom. I have seen Data Picker but I wasn't sure if I would be able to implement it without the actual picker, as I only need a calendar.

Comment: `DatePicker` is the only built-in class displaying a calendar-like UI; if you can't use that a `GridPane` would be the most likely choice for the layout in your own implementation.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    DatePicker startDatePicker = new DatePicker();
    DatePicker endDatePicker = new DatePicker();
    
    startDatePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    endDatePicker.setValue(startDatePicker.getValue().plusDays(1));

    vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Start Date:"));
    vbox.getChildren().add(startDatePicker);
    vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("End Date:"));
    vbox.getChildren().add(endDatePicker);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```